# How the pre and post increment work in c++?

Tags: c++, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

i want to know if increment/decrement operator results vary from compiler to compiler or it is independent of the compiler. as I am getting different results in different compilers of c/c++ (tested in G++, TDM, gcc) for the same expression.

Comment: The compiler doesn't execute it. The machine code it generates will vary depending on the processor that it's compiling for.

Comment: The "exact way" is clearly going to depend on the compiler and the language. (And, to nitpick: the compiler doesn't "execute" any of the code it finds; it simply compiles it to an intermediate form for the linker to use later.)

Comment: this is a useful tool for exploring what the compiler does to your code. http://gcc.godbolt.org/ just enter your code and it will show you the assembly code that gcc will generate. Remember to turn off optimizations if you want it to be an exact translation.

Comment: These operators can be overloaded in C++, I assume you are asking for built-in types (`int`, `float` ...) ? Your question should be more precise.

Comment: If you want to know the **exact way**, the only correct answer is to look at the source code for the compiler you care about.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the internal llvm assembly. Which isn't hard to do.

#### C++ code:

```
void preincrement() __attribute__((noinline));
void preincrement() {
    volatile int x = 10;
    volatile int y = ++x;
}

void postincrement() __attribute__((noinline));
void postincrement() {
    volatile int x = 10;
    volatile int y = x++;
}

int main()
{
    preincrement();
    postincrement();
}
```

#### Resultant LLVM Assembly (minus some leading and trailing text that isn't interesting):

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define void @_Z12preincrementv() #0 {
  %x = alloca i32, align 4
  %y = alloca i32, align 4
  store volatile i32 10, i32* %x, align 4
  %1 = load volatile i32* %x, align 4
  %2 = add nsw i32 %1, 1
  store volatile i32 %2, i32* %x, align 4
  store volatile i32 %2, i32* %y, align 4
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
define void @_Z13postincrementv() #0 {
  %x = alloca i32, align 4
  %y = alloca i32, align 4
  store volatile i32 10, i32* %x, align 4
  %1 = load volatile i32* %x, align 4
  %2 = add nsw i32 %1, 1
  store volatile i32 %2, i32* %x, align 4
  store volatile i32 %1, i32* %y, align 4
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define i32 @main() #1 {
  tail call void @_Z12preincrementv()
  tail call void @_Z13postincrementv()
  ret i32 0
}
```

We can see here pretty clearly the only difference: In the post increment version, we use the original value, instead of the upgraded value.

In both cases, we just use a traditional add opcode to do the real work.